# Remove Duplicates while Merging values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I remove duplicates and merge Account Types?

I have a call log that reports duplicate phones based on Account Type.

**For example:**

```
Telephone       | Account Type

304-555-6666    | R

304-555-6666    | C
```

- I know how to remove duplicate Telephones using RANK\MAXCOUNT
- But before removing duplicates I need to reset the Account Type to “B” is the duplicates have multiple account types.

In the example the surviving duplicate would be:

```
Telephone       | Account Type

304-555-6666    | B
```

**Warning, it is not guaranteed that duplicate phones have multiple Account Types.**

Example:

```
Telephone       | Account Type

999-888-6666    | R

999-888-6666    | R
```

Therefore the surviving duplicate should be:

```
Telephone       | Account Type

999-888-6666    | R
```

**How can I remove duplicates and reset the account type at the same time?**

```
--
-- Remove Duplicate Recordings
--
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  i.dateofcall ,
      i.recordingfile ,
        i.telephone ,        
        s.accounttype ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.telephone ORDER BY i.dateofcall DESC) AS 'RANK' ,
                    COUNT(i.telephone) OVER (PARTITION BY  i.telephone) AS 'MAXCOUNT'
FROM    #myactions i
        LEFT JOIN #myphone s ON s.interactionID = i.Interactionid 
) x
WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  i.dateofcall ,
      i.recordingfile ,
        i.telephone ,        
        s.accounttype ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.telephone ORDER BY i.dateofcall DESC) AS 'RANK' ,
        COUNT(i.telephone) OVER (PARTITION BY  i.telephone) AS 'MAXCOUNT',
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY i.telephone ORDER BY s.accounttype DESC ) AS 'ContPhone'
FROM    #myactions i
        LEFT JOIN #myphone s ON s.interactionID = i.Interactionid 
) x
WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
select
    x.dateofcall
    , x.recordingfile
    , x.telephone
    , case when count(*) > 2 then 'B' else max(x.accounttype) end accounttype
    (
    select
        i.dateofcall
        , i.recordingfile
        , i.telephone
        , s.accounttype
    from
        #myactions i
        LEFT JOIN #myphone s ON s.interactionID = i.Interactionid
    group by
        i.dateofcall
        , i.recordingfile
        , i.telephone
        , s.accounttype
    ) x
group by
    x.dateofcall
    , x.recordingfile
    , x.telephone
```

Comment: What happens if both phones in the MAXCount are R?

Comment: Answered before OP's edit. My first thought is to count the number of Rs and check for it being the same as MAXCOUNT. I'll edit the SQL in a bit.

Comment: Are R, C & B the only account types? Or are there more? How many more?

Comment: There is only R and C. If a duplicate phone is found and they have R and C, then the account type should become B. But there is no guarantee that duplicate phones will have multiple Account Types. Duplicates could include 2 Account types R or 2 Account types C. If that is the case then, the account type should remain R or C

Comment: OK, my new query should work no matter how many account types there are. It will change to B only if there are different types, preserving any consistent types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84413/discussion-between-sqlcurious-and-internet-engineer).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to put your business check in a case statement outside.

**EDIT:** I've also added the logic for B, R and C. Also done a sql fiddle- link to fiddle -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5ef5/7

```
SELECT 
    x.dateofcall,
    x.recordingfile,
    x.telephone,
    COALESCE(
        CASE WHEN x.maxcount>1 AND value>x.maxcount AND value<(2*x.maxcount) THEN 'B' ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN x.maxcount>1 AND value= (2*x.maxcount) THEN 'C' ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN x.maxcount>1 AND value= x.maxcount THEN 'R' ELSE NULL END,
        x.accounttype ) as accounttype, 
    x.rank,
    x.maxcount
FROM (
    SELECT  i.dateofcall ,
            i.recordingfile ,
            i.telephone ,        
            s.accounttype ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.telephone ORDER BY i.dateofcall DESC) AS 'RANK' ,
            COUNT(i.telephone) OVER (PARTITION BY  i.telephone) AS 'MAXCOUNT',
            SUM(CASE WHEN s.accounttype LIKE 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY  i.telephone) as Value
    FROM 
        myactions i LEFT JOIN myphone s 
        ON s.interactionID = i.Interactionid 
    ) x
WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT]
```